# Getting error in finding spatial reference of shapefile

Tags: python, gdal, ubuntu

I am working on Ubuntu, when I tried to read spatial reference of shapefile it give me this error.

```
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToProj4()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "< stdin >", line 1, in < module >
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetSpatialRef'

Help me to remove it

Comment: Maybe an upper case issue.... getSpatialRef instead of GetSpatialRef???

Comment: still getting same error      spatialRef = layer.getSpatialRef()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getSpatialRef'

Comment: What is layer??

Comment: Can you provide the whole code?

Comment: http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2009/tl_2009_us_state.zip (state polygon layer)

Comment: i didnot made any code only i am trying to learn python command using this layer

Comment: So layer variable contain a None type object. Try to get a  reference to a layer before and it should work

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your problem. You need a layer or a geometry or an EPSG code

With the [www2.census.gov/geo/tiger//TIGER2009/tl_2009_us_state.zip](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger//TIGER2009/tl_2009_us_state.zip) shapefile

```
from osgeo import ogr
file = ogr.Open('tl_2009_us_state.shp') # from www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2009/tl_2009_us_state.zip 
layer = file.GetLayer()
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
spatialRef.ExportToProj4()
'+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs '
spatialRef.AutoIdentifyEPSG()
spatialRef.GetAuthorityCode(None)
'4269'
```

With a geometry

```
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
spatialRef = geometry.GetSpatialReference()
spatialRef.ExportToProj4()
'+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs '
```

With an EPSG code ([EPSG:4269](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/))

```
spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4269)
spatialRef.ExportToProj4()
'+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs '
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I read the spatial reference of a shapefile.

```
from osgeo import ogr
file = ogr.Open("C:\file_path\file_name.shp")
layer = file.GetLayer()
spatial_ref= layer.GetSpatialRef()
print spatial_ref
```

To get the individual spatial reference attributes:

```
spatial_attr = spatial_ref.GetAttrValue('projcs')
print spatial_attr
```

This will output the projection coordination system, e.g. "WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_38N".

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetSpatialRef'
```

The error message means, that your `layer` variable is empty. Check the way you obtain it.